# How to enable null safety in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried flutter upgrade cmd but it didn't fix the problem.

When I click get dependencies, I get an error like the screenshot

and then if I try to Change pubspec.yaml

sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0

to
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0

it shows

> C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get Resolving dependencies... The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.2. Because mi_card depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed. The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety. For details, see dart.dev/null-safety Process finished with exit code 1

Can you tell me the best solution for this

[image]

Comment: can you try update version on those package, or use `any` in version

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh how do i do that?

Comment: Open your pubspec.yaml and change `cupertino_icons: any`

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh now there is a error in pubspec.lock

Comment: delete lock file

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\seren\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_card_flutter\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\seren\.gradle\caches\7.0.2\scripts\9ro1u0k9hdyieqwldgdt37f3r).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: BUILD FAILED in 1s
Flutter Fix: our project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle. To fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter doctor --verbose`. Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                   C:\Users\seren\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_card_flutter\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible with that Java version.

Comment: See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions:                                                             https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                            
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: this error is coming

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh

Comment: try `sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter upgrade` command in the console.